# How to insert data into table from a Powebuilder window

Tags: powerbuilder

I see Powerbuilder can able to perform data operations when a datawindow is placed on the screen but is there a way to update the database using a normal window using button click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete` and `Select` SQL statements directly into PBScript events, look for the "Using SQL in scripts" entry of the PB documentation.

For example:

```
int li_somekey = 42
delete some_table where some_value = :li_somekey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate data in PowerBuilder without using the datawindow but this is like buying a new car only to tow it behind your old car as a trailer.  Once you set up your transaction object with the database (something you would need to do regardless) updating, inserting, and deleting data is super easy via a datawindow (a visual component) or a datastore (a non-visual component).

Otherwise you can issue SQL statements (including Stored Procedure calls) from within PowerScript directly.  You should always check the return from the Transaction object for errors regardless.